# function to return a column separated list of column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create a function that returns a comma separated list of field name for any given table. The function should accept database, schema and table name as input as return the comma separated list.

I can do this in a stored procedure but I want to do this in a function so I can join it into datasets. However I am problems with dynamic sql is not allowed in function - so how can I do this?

here is the proc which i want to duplicate in a function

```
alter proc dbo.usp_generate_column_name_string
@database varchar(100),@schema varchar(100), @table varchar(100)

as

declare @str varchar(max) = '

select stuff((select '','' + name as [text()] from 
(
select c.name from ' + @database + '.sys.tables a
inner join ' + @database + '.sys.schemas b on a.schema_id = a.schema_id
inner join ' + @database + '.sys.columns c on  c.object_id= a.object_id
where b.name = '''+@schema+''' and a.name ='''+@table+''') x

for xml path ('''')),1,1,'''')


'
exec (@str)

go

exec dbo.usp_generate_column_name_string 'test' , 'dbo','jl1_tmp'
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to do it, one easier way is to insert the proc result into a temp table and use it in join

```
create table #coltemp(colList varchar(max))

insert into #coltemp
exec dbo.usp_generate_column_name_string 'test' , 'dbo','jl1_tmp'

select * from #coltemp
```

check the following question to know about diff ways to insert proc results into temp table [Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic idea:

```
create function usp_generate_column_name_string (
    @schema varchar(100),
    @table varchar(100)
)
returns varchar(max) as
begin
    return (select stuff( (select ',' + column_name
                           from information_schema.columns
                           where table_name = @table and table_schema = @schema
                           for xml path ('')
                          ), 1, 1, ''
                        )
           );
end;
```

Notes:

- This doesn't handle special characters in the column names.  I'm not sure how you want to escape those, but the logic is easily adjusted.
- Database is left out.  That is much harder in SQL Server, because the system tables are organized by database.  If that is a requirement, you basically cannot do this (easily).